# Ms access equivalent to Cast as Bit of sql server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, checkbox, casting, equivalent

I could load data in datagridview in c# from ms sql server and cast whatever column I want to Bit as follows:

`select Cast(col as Bit)`.

As a result in the datagridview the column will be shown as a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.

How I can accomplish that using Ms access database query? I tried using CBool but its displaying the results in textbox column not in checkbox column.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Abs(CBool(col))`.

A boolean displays as true/false by default, but the underlying values are 0 for false and -1 for true. By using `Abs`, you cast that to an absolute number (1 for true), and also cause it to display as a number.

Do note that your client chooses how to display things, so if you want to display it as a checkbox, you need to configure your datagridview to do so.

Comment: How to configure datagridview for that?